# pass the address to a function and assign it to another variable

Tags: c

```
   if ((pos < n) && (key == ptr->keys[pos].value))
        function(&ptr->keys[pos]);
```

here i need to pass the address of `ptr->keys[pos]` to function, and i have done it as shown above, i am calling this "function" inside another function

```
    inline struct return_values *function(struct classifier *fun_ptr)
    {
        struct return_values *r; 
        r = malloc(sizeof(struct return_values));
        r->value1 = Duplicate;
        r->value2 = (void *)get;
        return r;
    }
```

the definition of function is as shown above i have to assign the address of `ptr->keys[pos]` to  `r->value2`

the structure return_values is as shown below

```
    struct return_values
    {
        KeyStatus_t value1;
        void* value2;
    }
```

how to assign the address of `&ptr->keys[pos]` to `r->value2`, i am able to pass the address to function form there how to assign that address to `r->value2` and i dont want to change  structure `return_value` in any case as it will have effect my entire code please help.

Comment: There is no way of telling without having the full code. What is struct classifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the address to fields of a struct can cause trouble depending on your runtime (and is bad style, but that's an opinion).
Instead of:

```
function(&ptr->keys[pos]);
```

- You should either pass the pointer to the struct:

  `function(ptr);`

  and let the function de-reference it (not encapsulated but flexible).
- or just call the function with the value stored inside that field, and assign to that field when the function returned like so:

  `ptr->keys[pos] = function(ptr->keys[pos]);`